# Show price in Woocommerce product custom loop

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce Bookings with only a base cost filled. No other rules. How do I display product price in a loop like this?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
ID is: <?php the_ID(); ?>
Title is: <?php the_title(); ?>
Price: <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ) ); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The price field didn't show anything

**UPDATE**

another code I tried:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product_Booking($productID);
$base_price = $product->get_price();
$product_data = $product->get_data();
$product_pricing = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', true);
?>

<?php echo $product_pricing; ?> 
<?php echo $base_price;?>
```

both also return the value of zero

**ANOTHER TRY**

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product_Booking($productID);
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$base_price = $product->get_price();
$product_data = $product->get_data();

$product_pricing = $product_data['pricing'];
foreach($product_pricing as $key => $princing ){
   $pricing_type           = $princing['type'];
   $pricing_base_cost      = $princing['base_cost'];
   $pricing_base_modifier  = $princing['base_modifier'];
   $pricing_cost           = $princing['cost']; 
   $pricing_modifier       = $princing['modifier'];
   $pricing_from           = $princing['from'];
   $pricing_to             = $princing['to'];
}

$pricing_data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', false); ?>

<?php echo $pricing_data; ?>
```

nothing works :( they're all either showing blanks or showing zero.
Can anyone help point in the right direction?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (from the [docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-accommodation-bookings/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-accommodation-booking.php)):

```
$product = new WC_Product_Booking($productID);
//don't know if you need 'echo'
echo $product->get_price_html()
```

If not, I think the logic of 2nd snippet it's ok, but probably **productID != postID**,
so another solution would be:

- find the **postID** for that **productID**
- call  get_post_meta( **postID**, '_wc_booking_pricing', true);
- print the price

### EDIT

---

My answer's too long for being posted in the comments.

Are you sure that you are set correctly the product from wp-admin?

In order to do the second suggestion, you need access to the database.
Get the ID of the post(product) in wp-admin when you create/modify it, you should have in the url something like {URL}/wp-admin/id=123.

Once you have the ID go in wp_post_meta table in the DB and look for all the fields with that post_id, and check if you can find the correct price.

Once you find it, you can call get_post_meta(correctID,correctKey)

Comment: thanks .. apparently get_price_html() is for woocommerce accommodation bookings .. the text returned is "Free" .. I'm not sure how to implement your second suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're pulling the right meta key, could be related with you using `esc_url()`, when you should be using just `esc_html()`. I'd try that.

Comment: Try to check your product price then buddy.